# Is there a way to implement statically-defined associative arrays in Perl 5?

Tags: perl, hash, crystal-lang

If I have some hash with the (absolutely) static set of keys, can I avoid calculating of hash functions on each access to elements of this hash by key at run time?

Say, I have a static associative array `%saa` with the keys:

```
my %saa = (
 A => "aaa",
 B => "bbb",
 C => "ccc"
);
```

How to pre-calculate hash function values for these keys in compile time and use it in run time in such effective manner as I did when using indexed access to simple lists elements.

As I know for now, in perl5 it may be implemented only as emulation of hashes using lists (`use constant A=>0, B=>1...; $saa[A]="ddd"`).

Maybe there is more straightforward way to implement static associative arrays (also called "named tuples", not hashes) in Perl ?

For example, that's how the desired feature was [implemented in Crystal language](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.24.2/NamedTuple.html).

Comment: Perl 5 does not have static types. It doesn't even really have types at all. That's the whole idea of the language. You can make a hash read-only, but that's not what you want. The approach with `use constant` simply installs functions into your current namespace. That's not a data structure.

Comment: Do you mean a feature such that executing, e.g., `$value = $aaa{A}` at run time should not use hash lookup to determine `$value` but rather be equivalent to a simple assignment statement `$value = "ddd"`? So the compiler should substitute hash lookup `$aaa{A}` with the constant  `"ddd"` in this case?

Comment: I doubt that you'll have a performance hit from a hash. Did you profile your code?

Comment: I think $aaa{A} could be equivalent to $a[A] with the A value defined in compile time as some N (for example, N=0)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The closest thing to the functionality described in [`struct NamedTuple(**T)`](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.24.2/NamedTuple.html) is [`Const::Fast`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Const::Fast).

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Const::Fast qw( const );

my %language;

BEGIN {
    const %language => (
        name =>'Crystal',
        year => '2011',
    );
}

print "$language{$_}\n" for qw( name year other );
```

```
$ perl t.pl
Crystal
2011
Attempt to access disallowed key 'other' in a restricted hash at t.pl line 17.
```

**BUT** the check happens at run time. See [Neil Bowers' excellent review](http://neilb.org/reviews/constants.html) for performance information. The stats may have changed since then, but it should give you an idea.

An alternative is not to use hashes at all, but use [Class::XSAccessor](https://metacpan.org/pod/Class::XSAccessor) to define a simple class:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

package My::Language;
use Class::XSAccessor (
    constructor => 'new',
    getters => {
        name => 'name',
        year => 'year',
    },
);

package main;

my $language;

BEGIN {
    $language = My::Language->new(
        name =>'Crystal',
        year => '2011',
    );
}

print $language->$_, "\n" for qw( name year other );
```

[`Class::XSAccessor::Array`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Class::XSAccessor::Array) should be about 10%-15% faster:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

package My::Language;
use Class::XSAccessor::Array (
    getters => {
        name => 0,
        year => 1,
    },
);

package main;

my $language;

BEGIN {
    $language = bless ['Crystal', '2011'] => 'My::Language';
}

print $language->$_, "\n" for qw( name year other );
```

In all cases, the checks happen at run time.

Comment: Thank you bery much Sinan! How this const %hash was implemented internally? Is it somehow faster than generic hash in perl?

Comment: In `Const::Fast`, the data structure is [marked as readonly](https://metacpan.org/source/LEONT/Const-Fast-0.014/lib/Const/Fast.pm#L26) using an internal Perl API.

Comment: Class::XSAccessor's objects is not NamedTuple, but its staticcaly defined and its very fast. It is good replacement for arrays with elements addressed by constant symbols. Thank you again, i will prefer to use your solution!

Answer (score 3):

Perl already precomputes the hash of constant keys. The hash code is then retrieved at runtime. Additionally, hash keys are constant-pooled so that even if the hash collides, the string equality is simplified to a pointer comparison.

Therefore, the extra runtime cost of of a constant hash key lookup compared to a constant array index lookup is very low, especially compared to all the overhead that is incurred anyway due to the Perl data model.

How does this work?

During the optimization phase, the `S_maybe_multideref()` function in `op.c` folds consecutive dereference operations like `$x{foo}[0]{bar}` into a single opcode. Scalars for constant keys are set aside so that they are just a pointer lookup away. These scalars are prepared by the `S_check_hash_fields_and_hekify()` function, which creates the constant-pooled scalar using the `newSVpvn_share()` function which (after a few levels of macros) uses the `S_share_hek_flags()` function from `hv.c` which creates or fetches a hash entry key (HEK) structure in a global constant pool (which itself is a hash table).

During runtime, the hash lookup function notices that the key scalar is in fact a shared HEK, and directly retrieves the hash. This short-circuits most of the hash table lookup code in the `Perl_hv_common()` function.

This only works when using constant strings for hash keys. Otherwise, you still have to do the complete hash lookup.

Using constant array keys like `$struct[KEY_FOO]` in place of constant hash keys `$hash{foo}` is therefore not going to give you a noticeable performance benefit. Instead, the main benefit of the array approach is that you have to *declare* all constants up front, thus giving you some amount of static checking. This can e.g. detect typos. Note that hashes also support some checks:

- Using the `fields` pragma, you can *statically* restrict the hash keys that can be accessed *through a variable*. E.g. `my SomeClass $object` only allows `$object->{foo}` if the `SomeClass` class has declared a `foo` field. However, this is a very arcane, misleading, and discouraged feature of Perl. Please do not use it.
- Using “restricted hashes”, you can freeze the keys of a hash table (see `lock_keys()` in `Hash::Util`). This is a *runtime* check. This is the best approach if you want to get the typo-detection benefits. E.g. we could declare a kind of struct like:

  ```
  use Hash::Util qw(lock_keys);
  my %struct;
  lock_keys(%struct, qw(foo bar));

  $struct{foo};  # OK
  $struct{bar};  # OK
  $struct{qux};  # runtime error
  ```

Answer (score 2):

Since this is Perl, there are a number of ways to at least sort of do what you want. Here is a [tied hash](https://metacpan.org/pod/perltie#Tying-Hashes) implementation that does not do any hash lookups:

```
sub DrvtinyStaticHash::TIEHASH {
    my ($pkg, $A, $B, $C) = @_;
    bless [ $A, $B, $C ], $pkg;
}

sub DrvtinyStaticHash::STORE {
    my ($self,$key,$value) = @_;
    if ($key eq 'A')      { $self->[0] = $value }
    elsif ($key eq 'B') { $self->[1] = $value }
    elsif ($key eq 'C') { $self->[2] = $value; }
    else { die "DrvtinyStaticHash: Bad key: $key" }
}

sub DrvtinyStaticHash::FETCH {
    my ($self,$key) = @_;
    return $self->[0] if $key eq 'A';
    return $self->[1] if $key eq 'B';
    return $self->[2] if $key eq 'C';
    die "DrvtinyStaticHash: Bad key: $key";
}

tie my %saa, 'DrvtinyStaticHash', 'aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc';

print $saa{"B"};     # "bbb"
$saa{"C"} = 42;
print $saa{"D"};     # error: Bad key
```

You could generalize this to any package name and any set of keys with an unhealthy dose of `eval` calls.

Comment: `DrvtinyStaticHash::XS` will be out by the end of next quarter  :)

Comment: I don't think that will help enough. The problem is fundamental to using tie. I think a hash lookup is faster than a sub call (no matter whether the sub is written in Perl or XS).

Comment: $key eq 'A' and tied variables is not what i want. I want to simply pass names of the constants, not strings, as indexes. Ideally so: $saa[:myStaticIndex] = "value"; but not $saa["myStaticIndex"] = "value" (because conversion from string to integer value is a hash lookup - whether it will be "internal" hash table containing program symbols or "external" - for user-defined hash).

Comment: Conversion from string to int in this example is done with a sequence of `if...else` statements and string comparisons, not a hash lookup.

Comment: Are you kidding me? :)